# V-Lookup in IF-statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

I want a function that only does the V-Lookup when there is a value in the cell of the table of KM.

I have the code for a V-Lookup which works:

```
VERT.ZOEKEN(=[Km];'Prijs Km'!$A$2:B99;2)
```

But when I place it into an IF-statement it doesn't work anymore:

```
=ALS(Tabel1[@Km]= "";"NIETS";VERT.ZOEKEN(=[Km];'Prijs Km'!$A$2:B99;2))
```

Comment: it will be hard if not used english notation... open up your VBA-window via alt+F11. If there is no "Immediate" window hit ctrl+G. select the cell with the formula and enter in the "Immediate" window `?Selection.Formula`. You will get the english view of your formula, this will help a lot in helping you ;)

Comment: Take out the extra `=` in the formula.  I wouldn't think it should work in the first one. `=ALS(Tabel1[@Km]= "";"NIETS";VERT.ZOEKEN([Km];'Prijs Km'!$A$2:B99;2))`

Comment: @ScottCraner I knew it would be something silly!
Thank you. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: All good, glad to have helped.

Comment: @DirkReichel Thx, I used it for my next question ;)